Objects missing in schema builder
The standard objects from Educational Cloud is listed in Object Manager but is missing in object list in Schema builder.
What can be the cause?
Ex. LearningAchievement is missing but Account and Agreement_m__c is showing up.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You have the appropriate Permission Set License Assignments on your user, correct?  You should open a case with Salesforce.  I know that Industry objects can have lots of unexpected behavior.
